# How to say "a player whose turn it is now" in one word?

Tags: single-word-requests

Say there is a turn based strategy video game or any turn based board game. Is there a single word to call a player whose turn it is now?

Comment: [Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/on) licenses the adjective **on** in related usages: **adj**
... 
25. (postpositive) informal
a. performing, as on stage: I'm on in five minutes ... //
27. (Cricket) cricket (of a bowler) bowling >> I remember the expression 'John's on' for 'It's John's turn'.

Comment: "You're up" or "you're it" or "it's your turn".  And "you're next", "it's your roll", and probably several dozen others.

Comment: "Active player" isn't a single word, but it's what I've seen the most often for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no single word in English for a player in *any* game whose turn it is.

In chess, the most common term for this purpose is adjectival, as in, "the player **on move**".

In some games, there are specific terms, such as "Lead" in the card game of Bridge. This is jargon for "the player who has the *lead*", i.e. the one who will play the first card of the new round (or *trick*). In the game of Tag, the term is "It", and the change of turns is signaled by the announcement "You're It!".